# Affinity Designer: How to maintain the colour of the intersected object

Tags: path, illustration, affinity-designer

I have a rectangle and a circle (**fig1**). I would like to apply an intersection to these two objects.

For this, I duplicate the rectangle and then select the duplicated rectangle and the circle and apply an intersection.

After the intersection, the part of the circle overlapping the rectangle becomes of the colour of the rectangle (**fig2**).

I would like to know if there is a way of maintaining its original green colour like in **fig3**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the bottom object stays and the color of the top object vanishes when making an intersecion in A.Designer.

Try instead of intersection operation named "Divide". Delete the extras.

Before:

[image]

After applying "Divide" and moving the pieces apart:

[image]

You may still need the duplicate of the rectangle because like in many other programs exact seams are partially transparent and something can be seen through the about 1px wide partially transparent gap.